# Expand JSON from DataFrame column

Tags: json, python-2.7, pandas, request

I'd like to expand the JSON data in a DataFrame to have individual columns per KV pair.

```
                                                events
0     {u'category': u'8052', u'username': u'NULL', u...
1     {u'category': u'8052', u'username': u'NULL', u...
2     {u'category': u'8052', u'username': u'NULL', u...
3     {u'category': u'8052', u'username': u'NULL', u...
```

I tried a lot of things with `map`, but none of them did the trick. Mostly because the functions expect strings.

On a related note I get the JSON in one single columns from Python (2.7) requests. The reply had the JSON data, and I read it.

From the function:

```
results = requests.get(api_url + "/" + search_id + '/results',
                                  headers=aheaders, verify=False, auth=bauth).text.decode('utf-8')
return json.loads(results)
```

And from the actual call:

```
results = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
            ariel_query(server_ip, usern, passw, token)
)
```

Since expanding the column seems to be quite complex, there might be a simpler approach.

Comment: try using `json_normalize` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html

Comment: That puts everything in one row, instead of one column. 
`                                               events
0  [{u'category': u'8052', u'username': u'NULL', ...`

Comment: You have to work around  `record_path` and `meta` parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `json_normalize` with a parameter called `record_path`. As you saw in the listing the column was called events, which is the supplemented value. `json_normalize` will then return a `DataFrame` with columns.

```
results = json_normalize(
        requests.get(qradar_api_url + "/" + search_id + '/results',
                                  headers=aheaders, verify=False, auth=bauth).json(), record_path=keyword)
```

This is for Python 2.7 (requests is a little different for 3.x)